# Are there negative influences in the Web of Trust? If not, are there theoretical alternatives?

Tags: pgp, trust, web-of-trust

Suppose I encounter a trusted PGP key that isn't really who they say they are. I don't want to sign their key and promote that entity.

Can I somehow show my dissidence from the trust that everyone else is giving? I didn't see anything obvious on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust).

If the answer is "no", is there any research that illustrates how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's up to you if you want to trust (or not) person with a lot of signs. It's just a determinant of fairness.